# reference and arrays that can happen unexpectedly

Tags: php, arrays

can some one please explain the reference here? 
I know that reference is causing it to happen but how?
why just in the index of 2? why not other ones?

I know what references does but in this particular example I am lost:

```
$a = array ('zero','one','two');
foreach ($a as &$v) {
}
foreach ($a as $v) {
}
print_r ($a);
```

output:

```
Array ( [0] => zero [1] => one [2] => one )
```

Comment: here some useful link http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php

Comment: [The PHP manual page for foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) refers to this phenomenon:
"Warning: Reference of a $value and the last array element remain even after the foreach loop. It is recommended to destroy it by unset()."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the first `foreach` loop, `$v` will be a reference to the last element in `$a`.

In the following loop `$v` will be assigned to `zero` then `one` and then to itself (it is a reference). It's current value is now `one` because of the previous assignment. That's why there are two `one`'s at the end.

For a better understanding: Your code is doing the same as the following lines:

```
// first loop
$v = &$a[0];
$v = &$a[1];
$v = &$a[2]; // now points to the last element in $a

// second loop ($v is a reference. The last element changes on every step of loop!)
$v = $a[0]; // since $v is a reference the last element has now the value of the first -> zero
$v = $a[1]; // since $v is a reference the last element has now the value of the second last -> one
$v = $a[2]; // this just assigns one = one
```

Comment: After the first loop, $v will be a reference to the last element in $a why it is not referenced to each of them?

Comment: The reference will get updated unless the first foreach loop finishes. If it finished the reference will point to the last element.

Comment: I cannot analyze it after loop it is assigned to value two so after that what's happening

Comment: "and then to itself" what?

Comment: Glad that you got it!! :D It was hard to explain.. Good question!

Comment: @Nickparsa If someone asks "How should I make to second last element of an array similar to the last one?" -> you should answer with your code!!! :D Hehe!

Comment: oops :D yea I should by the way thank you again  it was hard to explain and you did a great job!